# Why Java stacktrace only returns failure in finally block?

Tags: java

I've written some automation tests where I use syntax like -

```
try { 
   // Test case steps and validations
} finally { 
   // Clean up related to test
}
```

NOTE: This does not have `catch` block as my tests do not expect exceptions.

If test fails in `try` as well as `finally` block, only failures of `finally` are returned on console but not of `try`. Simple example here(TestNG is used here for assertions) -

```
try {
    Assert.assertEquals(true, false, "Boolean values did not match");
} finally {
    Assert.assertEquals(100, 10, "Integer values did not match");
}
```

In this case, only details of finally failures are returned.

This does not help to identify actual failure of test looking at the console.

I would like to understand why Java does not return both failure details on console which can help user to identify failure cause at very first look.

Comment: I'd investigate your test framework's ability to set up / tear down tests, rather than set up and tear down manually in your tests (as you appear to be doing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same thing can be observed with throwing exceptions:

```
try {
    throw new RuntimeException("Message 1");
} finally {
    throw new RuntimeException("Message 2");
}
```

Here, only `Message 2` is printed:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Message 2
```

This is because when `finally` throws an exception, any exceptions in `try` is "discarded and forgotten":

JLS section 14.20.2

> - If the run-time type of V is not assignment compatible with a catchable exception class of any catch clause of the try statement,
>     then the finally block is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes abruptly because of a throw of the value V.
>   - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (**and the throw of value
>       V is discarded and forgotten**).

Answer (score 1):

Because under the hood `Assert.assertEquals()` uses `Assert.fail()` to throw an `AssertionError` to signal the error.

The exception in `finally` block will replace and discard the one thrown in `try` block as per [14.20.2. Execution of try-finally and try-catch-finally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2).

Comment: It doesn't have higher priority. If a `finally` block throws exception while already processing an exception, it **replaces** the exception, or as the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) calls it: The original exception is "discarded and forgotten".

Answer (score 1):

That is because a new exception thrown from a `finally` block *replaces* the exception thrown from the `try` block, as documented in the Java Language Specification, section [14.20.2. Execution of try-finally and try-catch-finally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2):

> If execution of the `try` block completes abruptly because of a `throw` of a value `V`, then there is a choice:
>
> [...]
>
> If the `finally` block completes abruptly for reason `S`, then the `try` statement completes abruptly for reason `S` (and **the `throw` of value `V` is discarded and forgotten**).

Since the `finally` block doesn't even know of the original exception, it cannot do anything about it.

However, if you `catch` the original exception, you can include it as a *suppressed* exception (Java 7+), but it's a bit convoluted:

```
AssertionError originalError = null;
try {
    Assert.assertEquals(true, false, "Boolean values did not match");
} catch (AssertionError e) {
    originalError = e;
    throw e;
} finally {
    try {
        Assert.assertEquals(100, 10, "Integer values did not match");
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        if (originalError == null)
            throw e;
        originalError.addSuppressed(e);
        throw originalError;
    }
}
```